# Show info of DB in the page

Tags: html, mysql, angular

I am trying to post on the html the info from my database and it's not working. Here is the code in my html. Name of my db is softball_leagues. Table players, called the team name

```
   <div class="container">
       <div ng-repeat="teams  in softball_leagues" ng-click="adminViewBusiness()">

        <div class="thumbnail">
            <h5 ng-click="players(team_name)" class="caption">
                <br>View info form DB
                {{team_name}}
            </h5> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: html cannot save data in database, many other programming languages - can, but html - no

Comment: @IlyaBursov im using node.js and angular js. This is the code to the .html

Comment: If the table of the database is `players`, then the **ng-repeat** must be `<div ng-repeat="teams in players" ng-click="adminViewBusiness()">`. By the other hand you must give more details about your code.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez i have this and it still no working [https://plnkr.co/edit/bQPeWUn3zI0t9Rcl1LRb?p=preview]

Answer (score 0):

You've said that your database's name is softball_league, in that case you need to get the results from the database for the teams and by calling the backend and fill in an array of objects (or strings, depending on what your backend is returning as a result) with the results. If you've done that, and under assumption that in `ng-repeat="teams in softball_league"` softball_league is that array and teams is an object from that array, then instead of using `{{team_name}}` for printing the name of the team, you must use the variable teams.team_name, otherwise I don't see from where team_name is coming when you are trying to print it, and even if it is defined variable in your class code, it will be a constant value instead of a differrent value for each  iteration of the ng-repeat directive.

Comment: I have this know [https://plnkr.co/edit/bQPeWUn3zI0t9Rcl1LRb?p=preview]

Comment: I saw the code but can't figure out from where do you get the value for team_name